# WebAPI allow only single date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, date-format

Inside my WebAPI I have method that allows user to register to my page.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("create")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateAccount(MyModel newAccount)
{
}
```

My model has DateTime field that is filled with date when request is made.
Everything works fine when user sends for example `1990-02-07` but for `07.02.1980` I get incorrect value inside my model - date nad month switch values.
I know I can create custom `JsonConverter` as shown [here](http://blog.dinklabs.com/2014/07/web-api-culture-specific-date-time.html), but can I do it globally?

Inside `Startup.cs` I have:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime;
```

but still I can do request with invalid date format.

I would like to globally allow single format for date and time.
I would like to allow `yyyy-MM-dd` (1990-02-07) and `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` (2016-07-28 11:56:00) and return badrequest or invalid request when other format is specified without even processing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Json media formatter for date and register it for DateTime type.. Here is the example code for media formatter

```
public class JsonDateFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Do date formatting here
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(DateTime))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is how you can register it in `Startup.cs`

```
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonDateFormatter());
```

Comment: Thank You so much for suggesting this. Inside `ReadFromStreamAsync` I must read string and convert it to DateTime. I should throw exception if format is other that I'm expecting? Ideally I'd like to return error `Invalid format`, same way as ValidationAttribute is returning. Can I do that using custom formatter?

Comment: @Misiu You need to read stream in 'ReadFromStreamAsync and then convert it to date format you want. You can throw exception from this method but I don't think so you can do it the same way as ValidationAttribute

Comment: I'll try that and let You know if it works as I would like it to work.